# The datasheet says that USB operates on 1.8v instead of 3.3v, do I need some sort of logic level shifter in my circuit?

Tags: usb, google-coral, imx6

I'm trying to design a breakoutboard and connect the coral chip to my imx6 SoC vis usb. I'm assuming that the imx6 is using 3v3 logic because it doesn't indicate otherwise and everything I've connected to it via usb thus far works fine. The data sheet of the Coral Edge TPU says that it operates on 1.8V. Do I need to account for this somehow in my design by assing a logic level shifter or something like that to my schematic? I don't even really know if USB operates at 3.3v logic level either I'm just confused about why they would say that in the datasheet.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related question, hardware design or question is therefore off-topic. Please try at https://electronics.stackexchange.com, but before you doing that, take a look at your question and provide the necessary information (url for datasheet, board that you are referring to), etc. in order for people to help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an electronics question, not a programming question. Try [electronics.se] instead.